# GCP BigQuery PHP client get list of projects

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

This is my current code that brings back just one project.
How can i get a list of all accessible projects?

```
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/../gcp-bigquery-key.json');
$scopes = implode(' ', [Google_Service_Bigquery::BIGQUERY]);

$client->setScopes($scopes);
$service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);

$tQ = $service->projects->listProjects();
print_r($tQ);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using BigQuery token for as authorisation. As that key is valid for BigQuery, you are getting the project which contains that BigQuery.

For seeing all projects you can check this code found in the documentation [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list#authorization-scopes):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google-CloudResourceManagerSample/0.1');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform');

$service = new Google_Service_CloudResourceManager($client);

$optParams = [];

do {
  $response = $service->projects->listProjects($optParams);

  foreach ($response['projects'] as $project) {
    // TODO: Change code below to process each `project` resource:
    echo '<pre>', var_export($project, true), '</pre>', "\n";
  }

  $optParams['pageToken'] = $response->getNextPageToken();
} while ($optParams['pageToken']);
?>
```